# Integer solutions of an equation

Tags: number-theory

Find all the integral solutions of the equation

$x^4-10y^4=1$

I know how to solve when the power is 2. But I don't know how to solve this equation. 
One idea which I thought is to split it into two square factors and solve them simultaneously. But it is becoming complicated and I am not able to understand whether they will be all the solutions or not. 
Please provide a detailed solution if possible.

Comment: Perhaps write it as $10y^4=x^4-1=(x^2+1)(x+1)(x-1)$ and see which factors 2 and 5 can divide.

Comment: Can you solve $p^2-10q^2=1$?  Of those solutions, which are perfect squares?

Comment: Yeah... x+1 and x-1 can't both be fourth powers and other than 2 must be relatively prime... so that rules out all be the lowest possible values of x.

Comment: If you can find all the so solutions to $p^2 - 10q^2 =1$ then $x^2=p$ and $y^2 = q$ will be a subset of these.

Comment: Any fourth power of a number that is not a multiple of $17$ is $\pm1$ or $\pm4$ $\mod 17$.

Then $10y^4+1$ is $11$, $9$, $12$ or $7$ $\mod 17$, so if the equation has any solution, then $17\mid y$.

Comment: @ajotatxe and how to find the solution when y is a multiple of 17?

Answer (score 0):

*Hint* (not a solution): Pell's equation $X^2-10Y^2=1$ has fundamental solution $(X,Y)=(19,6)$, thus all non-zero solutions are given by Pell's [recurrence formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pell%27s_equation)
${\displaystyle X_{k}+Y_{k}{\sqrt {10}}=(X_{1}+Y_{1}{\sqrt {10}})^{k},}$

$$
(19,6),(721,228),(27379,8658),(1039681,328776),(39480499,12484830),\ldots
$$
Now show from Pell's formula, that no pair is of the form $(X,Y)=(x^2,y^2)$ for integers $x,y$.

Comment: Would $(X,Y) = (1,0)$ not be a valid solution?

Comment: Yes, you are right. I assumed $X,Y\neq 0$.

Comment: How to prove the second part of your answer that there is no square solution

Comment: Not really sure what you have in mind here. $Y_{153k_0} \equiv 0 \mod{17^2}$ for every $k_0$.

Comment: @MikeBennett I am sorry; I should say honestly, that I did not solve the question, but think it should be possible to do it with Pell's equation.

Comment: @user364168 Since you say you have solutions for powers of $2$, and you wonder " whether they will be all the solutions or not", I leave this for you. Maybe you could show us your proof for powers of $2$?